# Bash script excluding first element

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that is gathering active users on a machine and then I am going to curl away the data. The issue is that the first item in the list won't show up, it is gathering everything after the first. Can anyone explain why?

```
#!/bin/bash
users=$(ps -eo ruser,rgroup | grep users | sort | uniq | cut -d ' ' -f1)
while read -r users
do
   newVar=$newVar$(awk '{print "user_name{name=\""$users"\"}", 1.0}');
done <<< "$users"
```

Then I curl newVar which should be a concatenation of all users in the format that is required.

Comment: `awk` and `read` are both reading from the same standard input.

Comment: `awk` reads all of the input on the first iteration, so there's nothing left for the `while` loop to process.

Comment: Why are you using both a `while` loop and `awk`? It seems like you only need one loop.

Comment: Also, you never set the variable `users` inside `awk`. It's not the shell variable, since the awk script is in single quotes.

Comment: Can you show the desired result?

Comment: @Barmar what I would like to be the output would be "user_name{name="doej"} 1.0 user_name{name="janed"} 1.0 " and so forth for all users

Comment: So just pipe the output of the `ps` pipeline to `awk`. Why do you need the `users` variable?

Comment: @Barmar I am fairly unfamiliar with bash. I was following an example from another user. Ill try your pipe idea!

Comment: Why are you using `ps -o ruser,rgroup` if you're eventually going to remove the group with `cut`?

Comment: Oh, I see, it's because you just want the usernames in the `users` group with `grep users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the `users` variable or the `while read` loop. Just pipe the output of the `ps` pipe directly to `awk`.

You don't need `cut`, since `awk` can select the first column with `$1`. And `sort | uniq` can be combined into `sort -u`.

```
newVar=$(ps -eo ruser,rgroup | grep users | sort -u | awk '{printf ("username{name=\"%s\"} 1.0", $1)
```